# Prove that $13^n -4^n$ is divisible by $9$ for every integer $\geq $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

> Prove that $13^n - 4^n$ is divisible by $9$ for every integer $n$ is greater than or equal to $1$.

I have written down my answer but I don't know if it is correct.

$    13(13^k) - 4^{(k+1)}$
$=    9(13^k) + 4(13^k) - 4{(4^k)}$
$=    9(13^k) + 4(13^k - 4^k)$
$=    9(13^k) + 4(9a)$ where $9a = 13^k -4^k$
$=    9(13^k + 4a)$
$=    9b$ where $b=13^k + 4a$

Comment: Do you mean $13^n-4^n$ divisible by 9?

Comment: did you mean $13^n-4^n?$

Comment: Yes, I did mean that.

Comment: Your proof is correct. Just that it would be better if you verify that your base case ($n=1)$ is correct and also write your induction hypothesis and where did you apply the hypothesis clearly.

Comment: This indeed seems correct. However you should define $b$ and your proof would become more understandable if you were too add some explanation between steps

Comment: I did that in my paper but I did not mention it in this post :)

Comment: Thank you all for your help, I was worried I did something wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Just use $a^n -b^n=(a-b)(a^{n-1} + ... + b^{n-1})$

Another way is using induction by n as you did it (more or less) in the OP.

Comment: I have to prove it first with a notation our lecturer gave us. n=(any positive integer), n = k then n = k + 1.

Comment: @Damo Do you mean by induction?

Comment: Yes, we are using mathematical induction.

Comment: @Damo You have to specify that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove this by induction.

---

**First, show that this is true for $n=1$:**

$13^{1}-4^{1}=9$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$13^{n}-4^{n}=9k$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$13^{n+1}-4^{n+1}=$

$13\cdot13^{n}-4\cdot4^{n}=$

$13\cdot13^{n}-(13-9)\cdot4^{n}=$

$13\cdot13^{n}-13\cdot4^{n}+9\cdot4^{n}=$

$13\cdot(\color\red{13^{n}-4^{n}})+9\cdot4^{n}=$

$13\cdot\color\red{9k}+9\cdot4^{n}=$

$9\cdot13k+9\cdot4^{n}=$

$9\cdot(13k+4^{n})$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: So there are multiple answers to this question right?

Comment: @Damo: Yes, this one is by induction (as you can see from the opening statement that I just added).

Comment: You wrote 9⋅(13k+$4^n$) and my answer was 9b where b=$13^k$+4a. Are they both equal then?

Comment: @Damo: Hmmmmm... Yes, they look identical. I did not quite understand your answer to begin with, due to the use of $a$ and $b$, but I see what you meant now. You probably just want to emphasize that you are using induction, by adding a base case, an assumption and an inductive step. This is how my answer is written, which I think is clearer. However, due to the similarity to yours, I am willing to delete it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

since $$13\equiv 4 \mod 9$$ we get $$13^n-4^n\equiv 4^n-4^n\equiv 0 \mod 9$$

Answer (score -1):

Take base case $ n=1$, $9$ is divisible by $9$. Assume it to be true for $ n>=1$, then replace $n$ by $n+1$.

$13.13^n -4.4^n $ can be written as $9.13^n \,  + 4.(13^n-4^n)$ and both parts of it are divisible by 9.